# Problems with the active class on multi slide toggle

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with the active class on my accordian as it doesn't take into account the click of another option.  It needs to be active when open

```
$('.toggleBlock').hide();
$('.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggleBlock')
    $('.toggleBlock').not(elem).hide('slow');
     elem.toggle('slow');

    $(this).parent().find(".togglelink").toggleClass("active")
});
```

Fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/ktcle/njx9b6vh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove class `.active` on all elements but the one clicking and toggle the one you click like this

```
$(this).closest('.lists').find(".togglelink").not(this).removeClass("active");
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/njx9b6vh/4/)

You can simplify the code abit more like this

```
$('.togglelink').not(this).removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/njx9b6vh/8/)

Answer (score 1):

this would work on the end of the js function

```
$(this).parents('ul.lists').find(".togglelink.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().find(".togglelink").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/njx9b6vh/3/)

added new line for removing other active classes who has class

```
 $('.toggleBlock').hide();
 $('.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var elem = $(this).next('.toggleBlock')
     $('.toggleBlock').not(elem).hide('slow');
     elem.toggle('slow');
     $(".togglelink").removeClass("active") // added new line
     $(this).parent().find(".togglelink").toggleClass("active")
 });
```